# How can I configure Apache 2 to have 2 sites with nested documentRoot?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I need the following configuration:

- access the page at `project/www/index.php` at the URL `site.dev/index.php`
- access the page at `project/www/admin/index.php` at the URLs `site.dev/admin/index.php` and `admsite.dev/index.php`

I have the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site` as the following:

```
<VirtualHost site.igoru.dev>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName site.igoru.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site/www
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.site.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.site.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost admsite.igoru.dev>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName admsite.igoru.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site/www/admin
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.site.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.site.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I restart Apache, it says that the first virtualhost overlaps with the second, and the first had precedence. "Perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive". When I open the URLs, both point to the www/index.php file.

I've read a little the documentation about that directive, but it didn't help me.
I'm a little noob with apache configs, and would like some help with this problem.

TY in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `VirtualHost` blocks point at hostnames, they're binding to every request that comes in to the address that those names resolve to.  Presumably, those resolve to the same address, and so the first block gets the address and the second gets nothing.

You probably already have a `NameVirtualHost` directive somewhere; check `ports.conf`.  If not, set one (`NameVirtualHost *:80`), then change your `VirtualHost` blocks to match the name that's being configured for host headers:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site.igoru.dev
        ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName admsite.igoru.dev
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I changed the VirtualHost names for `*:80`, as my `ports.conf` has the NameVirtualHost as you said. But now, when I restart Apache, it throws those warnings: `_default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence` and `NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`

Comment: What do your `VirtualHost` blocks look like now?

Comment: http://pastie.org/1855560

Comment: Seems like your `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive is not taking effect.

Comment: and how can I doscover anything about that, or fix it? This line is in my `ports.conf` as you said. Additionally, I'm using the pristine apache2, as it came from Ubuntu 10.10 package manager.

Comment: Try putting the `NameVirtualHost` at the top of your site file and see if that works.